# Log the text of an expression and its result without C preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, logging, language-agnostic, c-preprocessor

I use this macro in C/C++ very frequently:

```
#define MYLOG(x) (std::cout << "Value of " << #x << " is: " << x << std::endl);
```

Its used like this:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
MYLOG(x+y);
```

with the result being this:

```
Value of x+y is: 3
```

I have yet to duplicate this in any language that doesn't use the C preprocessor. Is it possible in any other language? I would like to be able to start using it elsewhere. Note: eval doesn't count. I want to see the expression in my code, not a string, so that I can still have syntax highlighting and autocomplete.

Comment: I don't think C/C++ tokenizer pre-processor operator # exists anywhere else.

Comment: I see very little value with this. Log should show what the value is, not how it was calculated (`log("square: ", width*height)` vs `log("width*height", width*height)`) as that is an implementation detail.

Comment: @user694733: it's very useful actually, particularly for messages in failing assertions where you want to know both the expression and the values that didn't match expectations.  That said, not much point asking for a language agnostic solution unless you're prepared to introduce an extra pre-processing stage, in which case you can actually use the C/C++ preprocessor, or something more powerful like M4, but questions asking for tool suggestions are off-topic on S.O.

Comment: You can do it in Lisp.

Comment: @TonyD While there might be some special case I don't know about, in general it's more useful to know what happened and where. Expression can be found in code anyway (unless it's dynamic, but then you are probably using eval anyway). Descriptive message is more helpful in locating the the problem, than vague expression in my opinion. But as you stated, this question is not really answerable in it's current form, so it's pointless to try to guess what the actual use case for this is.

Comment: @user694733: not infrequently the source code is very descriptive and inherently reliable indication of a test or issue, and it may be of value even to readers of log files or error output who have no access to the source code, indicating how runtime data (including user interaction, file data, network traffic etc.) has met or not met expectations.  For an even simpler and more common use, consider `LOG("x " << escape(x) << ", y " << escape(y));` which might be more concisely, reliably and flexibly written ala `LOG(VAL(X) << ", " << VAL(Y));` - the longer the identifiers the more benefit.

Answer (score 1):

No, in both C and C++ the compiler removes symbol information. `#x` creates a string in the preprocessor, and the compiler does save strings.

Other languages with a stronger reflection capability may offer the ability to reflect on expressions. In particular, pure interpreted languages use just the string representation so they can trivially print that. However, that's where you object against `eval`. I don't understand why, some languages are 100% `eval`.